# Delete every node and edge from Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to delete every node and edge of any type from a Neo4j database. There are different ways of deleting nodes and edges suggested on SO. However, since my database is huge, and since all these methods rely on first querying for edges/nodes and then deleting them, which leads to loading (at least their indexes) into memory, these methods fail for my use case with the out-of-memory error. See the following example.

```
match ()-[r]->() delete r
match (n) delete n
```

> Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError: There is not enough memory to perform the current task. Please try increasing 'dbms.memory.heap.max_size' in the neo4j configuration (normally in 'conf/neo4j.conf' or, if you are using Neo4j Desktop, found through the user interface) or if you are running an embedded installation increase the heap by using '-Xmx' command line flag, and then restart the database.

For different reasons, I cannot increase the amount of configured memory.

One *radical* solution is to delete the database's files which would lead to deleting the database effectively (even resetting the indexes). In my use case, this approach has its downsides, e.g., some of our applications rely on a set import path to bulk load data (e.g., `Neo4jDesktop\relate-data\dbmss\dbms-...\import\`) where deleting and re-creating the database requires updating all those dependent applications.

I was wondering if there is any efficient approach other than these to delete all nodes and edges from a huge Neo4j database---ideally without needing to loading/query the nodes/edges first.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Neo4j 4.3 and above, you can simply use:

```
DROP DATABASE database_name IF EXISTS <-- Best Way
```

OR you can use use `CALL` syntax, like this:

```
MATCH (n)
CALL { WITH n
DETACH DELETE n
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 10000 ROWS;
```

The above query might not work on Neo4j Browser. To run it on neo4j Browser, try this:

```
:auto MATCH (n)
CALL { WITH n
DETACH DELETE n
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 10000 ROWS;
```

Finally, if your version is less than 4.x, you can try the `APOC` as suggested in another answer, or simply run this query multiple times until the output is zero.

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n LIMIT 10000
DETACH DELETE n
RETURN count(*);
```

Comment: Dropping the database will delete the whole database and not just nodes and edges; similar to what I explained in my question, this will lead to reconfiguring all the dependent apps in my use case.

Comment: ok. Did you try the second approach deleting data in transactions of a definite size. It should not give out of memory error. You can decrease the limit if you want to.

Comment: This is the error I get for the second one: `A query with 'CALL { ... } IN TRANSACTIONS' can only be executed in an implicit transaction, but tried to execute in an explicit transaction.`

Comment: Updated the answer. seems like there is some discrepancy in how the `CALL {} IN` syntax can be used via different mediums in neo4j

Comment: Not sure how it changed the database, but the third query corrupted the database such that only deleting files from the disk and creating a new database subsequently remained my only option.

Comment: Good answer! If you also update with how to deal with dense nodes (i.e. delete relationships first with call {} in transactions, then I think you have covered all the common options for removing data.

Comment: Also, database alias can be very useful (enterprise edition).
1. Prepare new db
2. Make old db read only
3. Re-alias new db
4. Drop old db

Comment: Database alias seems like a thing to explore. @Dr.Strangelove what exactly happened to your db?

Comment: Not sure what happened, Neo4j was not able to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apoc iterate function, this documentation will explain the details.

> https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/#usage-apoc.periodic.iterate

```
    CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (n) RETURN n",
  "DETACH DELETE n",
  {batchSize:10000, parallel:true})
```

This will delete the nodes and edges per 10k batches.

You can change the batch size based on your intuition.

Comment: I get the following error running this: `org.neo4j.kernel.DeadlockDetectedException: ForsetiClient... can't acquire UpdateLock... on NODE_RELATIONSHIP_GROUP_DELETE, because holders of that lock are waiting for ForsetiClient...`

Comment: You cn ignore it. I also get that warning. It is because it is deleting the nodes and edges by batch and in parallel mode. Check if the nodes are deleted or not.

Comment: In my case that does not lead to deleting nodes/edges, which I suppose could be related to that _warning_.